# Why are these points included in the following example if we are getting < or > sign?

Tags: calculus, inequality

When we are asked to find the values of x for which $ f(x) $ is increasing or decreasing we put $ f'(x)>0  $ or $ f'(x)<0  $. so we get strictly greater than or less than sign. Hence our answer must be of the form say $(a,b)$.
But it is always reported as $[a,b] $ why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, and $f'(x) > 0$ on [a,b].

If you assume that $f(a) > f(\xi)$ for some $\xi \in (a,b)$, it follows that, for some $c \in (a,\xi),\; f'(c) < 0$. But this contradicts $f'(x) > 0$ on $[a,b].$

So, by contradiction, $f(a) \le f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b).$

Using similar reasoning, $f(x) \le f(b)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

So we can conclude that $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$.